# Identify all permutations of a four-digit number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, combinations, vlookup, conditional-formatting

How do I, or what is a formula to, get Excel to identify all the same numbers that have the same four-digit numbers in a sequence in a worksheet. e.g. `1234`, `4321`, `2143` ?

There are one hundred numbers but if `1234` appear together in any order on the worksheet, I want it highlighted or such.

Comment: are always 1 2 3 4 the digit you are searching?

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this entirely in a formula (without using VBA) is a brute-force search.  The following formula returns TRUE if the digits 1, 2, 3, 4 appear in any order in cell A1.  To highlight cells that meet the conditions, use this as input to a conditional formatting rule (in Excel 2007 or 2010, look for the rule type called "Use a formula to determine which cells to format").

```
=NOT(AND(ISERR(SEARCH("1234",TEXT(A1,"#"))),ISERR(SEARCH("1243",TEXT(A1,"#"))),ISERR(SEARCH("1324",TEXT(A1,"#"))),ISERR(SEARCH("1342",TEXT(A1,"#"))),ISERR(SEARCH("1423",TEXT(A1,"#"))),ISERR(SEARCH("1432",TEXT(A1,"#"))),ISERR(SEARCH("2134",TEXT(A1,"#"))),ISERR(SEARCH("2143",TEXT(A1,"#"))),ISERR(SEARCH("2314",TEXT(A1,"#"))),ISERR(SEARCH("2341",TEXT(A1,"#"))),ISERR(SEARCH("2413",TEXT(A1,"#"))),ISERR(SEARCH("2431",TEXT(A1,"#"))),ISERR(SEARCH("3124",TEXT(A1,"#"))),ISERR(SEARCH("3142",TEXT(A1,"#"))),ISERR(SEARCH("3214",TEXT(A1,"#"))),ISERR(SEARCH("3241",TEXT(A1,"#"))),ISERR(SEARCH("3412",TEXT(A1,"#"))),ISERR(SEARCH("3421",TEXT(A1,"#"))),ISERR(SEARCH("4123",TEXT(A1,"#"))),ISERR(SEARCH("4132",TEXT(A1,"#"))),ISERR(SEARCH("4213",TEXT(A1,"#"))),ISERR(SEARCH("4231",TEXT(A1,"#"))),ISERR(SEARCH("4312",TEXT(A1,"#"))),ISERR(SEARCH("4321",TEXT(A1,"#")))))
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is shorter (not surprisingly!) than @dodgethesteamroller's answer:

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D1,$A:$A,1,0),"")=D1`

with `Applies to` an appropriate range BUT only works for four digit numbers, not say 34451234, and assumes all possible permutations (24 for four digits) are separately listed in ColumnA.

Select the range within which you wish to identify the four digit sets (assumed to be Column D) and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:** add the formula above and <kbd>Format...</kbd>, select your choice of formatting, OK, OK.